# Java WebService thread creation

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

How can I create a new thread in a webservice? I need the thread to start on the "main" of the web service, NOT IN SERVER CALLS.

I need it as worker thread, so server calls will send messages to the thread - for work to be done in BG and will not block the server request.

I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `ThreadPool`, this is an object that you can submit tasks to which will then be executed on the thread(s) of that threadpool.

The easiest way to make a ThreadPool is to use one created by the [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class.

Comment: This is not clear from the question, but if the author is not creating it's own implementation and uses third-party ws stack, then we have problem here: most implementations already use thread pools and each thread in a pool is continuously reused. I'd consider starting new threads as a bad practice in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a static initialiser in your main class.

Here I am using one to create a timer task which re-reads my properties file every hour but you can use them for almost anything, including making new threads.

```
static {
  // Read my properties at start-up.
  readProperties ();
  // Start a new timer task to repeat every hour.
  int rate = Debug? 60*1000 : 1*60*60*1000;
  // Make a daemon scheduled thread to re-read properties.
  new Timer("Read properties timer", true).schedule( new TimerTask(){
      public void run() { 
          readProperties();
      }
    }, rate, rate);
}
```